# Adding ERC20 tokens to watch tokens

Tags: dapps

I have been running Ethereum Wallet for some time now and have used drag and drop to enter contract address for the ERC20 tokens that I watch. However, I have downloaded the Mist app. and have tried to drag and drop the contract address for the watch tokens and it keeps changing to the Ethereum Webpage instead of remaining on the token contract page. Therefore, it is impossible to drag and drop. I also copied the contract address and it will not allow me to paste a copy on the token watch page. How are you guys doing this so I can play too?

Answer (score 1):

To add a Token to your watch list:

- Open MIST Wallet and click on the "Contracts" tab.
- Scroll to the bottom and click Watch Token.
- Add the address of your contract
- Enter the information (name, symbol, decimals)

Repeat for all tokens... I don't see any documentation on a drag n drop function.

Answer (score 0):

Thats odd. It its working fine for me. Head to https://github.com/ethereum/mist and you might find something.